# Inner Join not matching accurately

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables which I am trying to join on a matching ID.

The format is usually a simple number, like 16.

However, in one of the tables some IDs are longer and contain letters as well and can end up looking like this: 16AfGs9.

I would think, okay, not a problem. However, my MySQL query is currently matching the ID 16 row to all IDs having 16xxx format.

Is it possible to have the INNER JOIN on an exact match?

The current query:

```
select * from t1 
inner join t2 
on t1.id=t2.customer_id
```

Comment: What's the query?

Comment: I currently run the simplest possible inner join:select * from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id=t2.customer_id

Comment: @HoneyBadger *`16 = '16AfGs9'`, which is clearly false.* You are wrong. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=654df9499b5e6432b0b335ac44719439 The comparing context is numeric in this case.

Comment: @Akina, that's madness, but I stand corrected, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a string comparison.  The column is clearly a string, so the comparison needs to be to a string:

```
where id = '16'
```

If you have ids in *different* tables and one is an integer and one a string, then you need to fix your data model!  In the meantime, you can convert to a string:

```
where cast(inttable.id as char) = stringtable.id
```

Comment: Yes. The table with integers is old data from the previous structure. The where clause actually fixed my problem, thank you.